# python: iterating through every item within parallel nested lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

I have the following list of various numpy arrays:

```
nparrays_list = [
    array([1, 2, 3, 4])
    array([5, 6, 7, 8]),
    array([9, 10, 11, 12])
]
```

I want to iterate through the entire list without affecting the shape of the list (i.e. I don't want to flatten the list) to obtain the following list of numpy arrays:

```
nparrays_list_Decimal = [
    array([Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3'), Decimal('4')])
    array([Decimal('5'), Decimal('6'), Decimal('7'), Decimal('8')]),
    array([Decimal('9'), Decimal('10'), Decimal('11'), Decimal('12')])
]
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np

nparrays_list_Decimal = []
for nparray in nparrays_list:
    nparray_Decimal = np.array([D(str(item)) for item in nparray])
    nparrays_list_Decimal.append(nparray_Decimal)
```

My issue is I'm dealing with a ton of data so creating a new list isn't ideal (i.e. wasted memory). Is there a simple way to iterate through every item in the original list, even if the items are in nested lists (or numpy arrays in this case)?

Comment: How you defined the `D`? And why `nparrays_list` is not a numpy array?

Comment: I guess you could at least save the temporary list by passing a `"<U8"` format and a generator. That would truncate your items to 8 chars.

Comment: `D` stands for Decimal. Let me edit that to make it more clear. And it's `nparrays_list` because it's a list of numpy arrays. I don't need the container to be a nparray as well

Comment: Why do you need `Decimal` type when you seem to have integers?

Comment: @dawg I used integers in this example here but my actual data has decimals. Quick follow-up question: will I lose precision / accuracy if I'm only dealing with integers? And what if I'm dividing the integers (I would guess no and yes for those questions, respectively)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will have a different object type inside the Numpy array, you will need to create new arrays (unless they are arrays of `dtype=object`)

Here is a demo of the fact you cannot have mixed types in a Numpy array:

```
>>> arr=np.array([1,2,3])
>>> arr
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> arr[1]="string"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'string'
```

Assigning a `Decimal` type to an array of ints does not change that element into a decimal type in the array; `arr[1]` is converted into a `Decimal` but then converted back into an int silently:

```
>>> arr
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> arr[1]=Decimal(arr[1])
>>> arr
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> type(arr[1])
<type 'numpy.int64'>
```

You can do:

```
>>> nparrays_list_Decimal=[np.array([Decimal(e) for e in arr]) for arr in nparrays_list]
>>> nparrays_list_Decimal
[array([Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3'), Decimal('4')], dtype=object), array([Decimal('5'), Decimal('6'), Decimal('7'), Decimal('8')], dtype=object), array([Decimal('9'), Decimal('10'), Decimal('11'), Decimal('12')], dtype=object)]
```

Or, just stick with a list of lists:

```
>>> LoL=[[Decimal(e) for e in arr] for arr in nparrays_list]
>>> LoL
[[Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3'), Decimal('4')], [Decimal('5'), Decimal('6'), Decimal('7'), Decimal('8')], [Decimal('9'), Decimal('10'), Decimal('11'), Decimal('12')]]
```

---

If *memory* is your concern, (and usually you don't need to worry about it so much with modest arrays) you can do a more memory efficient conversion by deleting the subarrays as you convert them:

```
from collections import deque 

nparrays_list=deque(LoA)   # the List of Arrays is garbage collected..
nparrays_list_Decimal=[]
while nparrays_list:
    # each sublist is garbage collected after being popped and iterated
    nparrays_list_Decimal.append(np.array([Decimal(e) for e in nparrays_list.popleft()]))

>>> nparrays_list_Decimal
[array([Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3'), Decimal('4')], dtype=object), array([Decimal('5'), Decimal('6'), Decimal('7'), Decimal('8')], dtype=object), array([Decimal('9'), Decimal('10'), Decimal('11'), Decimal('12')], dtype=object)]
```

Comment: The list comprehension is sufficient. Thanks. And based on your post and hpaulj's post, it sounds like memory isn't a limiting factor at all here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

```
import numpy as np

nparrays_list_Decimal = [list(map(float, lst)) for lst in nparrays_list]
```

Edit:

[From the Python Documentation on Decimals](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/decimal.html)

To use decimals try this

```
from decimal import *
nparrays_list_Decimal = [list(map(Decimal, lst)) for lst in nparrays_list]
```

Comment: How can I use this to convert the numbers to Decimal objects (which I need for greater precision)? Floats are too inaccurate

Answer (score 1):

```
nparrays_list = [
    array([1, 2, 3, 4])
    array([5, 6, 7, 8]),
    array([9, 10, 11, 12])
]
```

Don't worry about making new lists.  Lists just contain pointers to objects elsewhere in memory.  In this case the list only occupies the memory of 3 integers.  The components do take up memory - they are arrays with 4 element data buffers.

```
nparrays_list_Decimal = [
    array([Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3'), Decimal('4')]),
    array([Decimal('5'), Decimal('6'), Decimal('7'), Decimal('8')]),
    array([Decimal('9'), Decimal('10'), Decimal('11'), Decimal('12')])
]
```

is another small list, with 3 pointers.  You could put those pointers back in to the original `nparray_list`, but why?  Just to save 3 integers worth of space?

But what's significant is that the new arrays are not compatible, memory wise, with the originals:

```
array([Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3'), Decimal('4')])
```

is an object dtype array.  That is like a list, with pointers to those `Decimal(n')` objects else where in memory.  That has to be a new array; it can't replace the `np.int32` items in the original `array([1,2,3,4])`.

Why don't you just go from

```
nparrays_list = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12]
]
```

to:

```
nparrays_list_Decimal = [
    [Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3'), Decimal('4')],
    [Decimal('5'), Decimal('6'), Decimal('7'), Decimal('8')],
    [Decimal('9'), Decimal('10'), Decimal('11'), Decimal('12')]
]
```

In other words, stick with lists of lists.  Is an array of `Decimal` objects any more useful than a list of the same?

===============

Because `Decimal` defines many math operations, it is possible to perform some array math on an array of `Decimal` objects:

```
In [482]: arr = np.array([Decimal(i) for i in range(1,4)])
In [483]: arr
Out[483]: array([Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3')], dtype=object)
In [484]: arr + 1
Out[484]: array([Decimal('2'), Decimal('3'), Decimal('4')], dtype=object)
In [485]: 1 / arr
Out[485]: 
array([Decimal('1'), Decimal('0.5'),
       Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333')], dtype=object)
```

Speedwise this last statement is basically the same as:

```
np.array([1/i for i in arr])
```

It will be slower than `1/np.arange(1,4)`.

====================

You might get a little speed improvement by making the Decimal array with:

```
In [503]: np.frompyfunc(Decimal,1,1)(np.arange(3))
Out[503]: array([Decimal('0'), Decimal('1'), Decimal('2')], dtype=object)
In [504]: np.frompyfunc(Decimal,1,1)(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4))
Out[504]: 
array([[Decimal('0'), Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3')],
       [Decimal('4'), Decimal('5'), Decimal('6'), Decimal('7')],
       [Decimal('8'), Decimal('9'), Decimal('10'), Decimal('11')]], dtype=object)
```

In other tests I've found that `frompyfunc` has a modest (e.g. 2x) speed improvement over more explicit iteration expressions.  It also has the advantage of seamlessly handling multidimensional arrays.  It returns an `object` array.  Sometimes that's a problem; here that's just fine.

```
In [509]: timeit np.frompyfunc(Decimal,1,1)(np.arange(2000))
1000 loops, best of 3: 752 µs per loop
In [510]: timeit np.array([Decimal(str(i)) for i in np.arange(2000)])
100 loops, best of 3: 17.1 ms per loop
In [515]: timeit np.array([Decimal(i) for i in range(2000)])
100 loops, best of 3: 7.39 ms per loop
In [525]: timeit np.array([Decimal(i.item()) for i in np.arange(2000)])
100 loops, best of 3: 11.3 ms per loop
```

I wondered why you used `str(i)`.  But then I found that `Decimal` can only take a few of the `np.dtypes` (not `np.int32`).  My guess is the `frompyfunc` uses `item()` or the equivalent to produce Python scalars:

```
In [523]: np.frompyfunc(Decimal,1,1)(np.arange(2))
Out[523]: array([Decimal('0'), Decimal('1')], dtype=object)
In [524]: np.array([Decimal(i.item()) for i in np.arange(2)])
Out[524]: array([Decimal('0'), Decimal('1')], dtype=object)
```

`frompyfunc` must be doing the equivalent of `i.item()` to generate a Python scalar from the `np.int32` object.

Comment: I need the np.array container because I'm performing math operations that are made much easier by the numpy module

Comment: Yes, I added some examples where use of an object array is useful.  In any case, I don't think you can improve on speed or memory use.  You are going to have 1000's of `Decimal` objects, and 1000's of pointers to those objects, regardless of the container structure.

Comment: I added a demonstration of using `frompyfunc` to facilitate the `Decimal` array creation.

Comment: Sounds like memory isn't a big problem for me here and I can take the simple way out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over every item , you can do a nested for loop like this.

```
nparrays_list = [
        array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
        array([5, 6, 7, 8]),
        array([9, 10, 11, 12])   
    ]

for arr in nparrays_list:
  for i, item in enumerate(arr):
    arr[i] = Decimal(str(item))
```

Comment: When I try `item = Decimal(str(item))` on the last line nothing happens. How can I use this to convert all the values to Decimal objects?

Comment: @jcmetz21 Updated my answer for this

Comment: This does not convert the elements into `Decimal` objects. See hpaulj's post or my post.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have `numpy`, but the following may give you some direction to solve your problem:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import array
>>> array_list = [
    array.array('q', [1, 2, 3, 4]),
    array.array('q', [5, 6, 7, 8]),
    array.array('q', [9, 10, 11, 12])
    ]
>>> def iterate(iterable):
    for index_a, value_a in enumerate(iterable):
        try:
            for index_b, value_b in iterate(value_a):
                yield [index_a] + index_b, value_b
        except TypeError:
            yield [index_a], value_a


>>> for index, value in iterate(array_list):
    print(value, 'is at', index)


1 is at [0, 0]
2 is at [0, 1]
3 is at [0, 2]
4 is at [0, 3]
5 is at [1, 0]
6 is at [1, 1]
7 is at [1, 2]
8 is at [1, 3]
9 is at [2, 0]
10 is at [2, 1]
11 is at [2, 2]
12 is at [2, 3]
>>>
```

To complete the solution to your problem, automatic casting or type conversion can be supported:

```
>>> def iterate(iterable, cast):
    for index_a, value_a in enumerate(iterable):
        try:
            for index_b, value_b in iterate(value_a, cast):
                yield [index_a] + index_b, value_b
        except TypeError:
            yield [index_a], cast(value_a)


>>> import decimal
>>> for index, value in iterate(array_list, decimal.Decimal):
    print(repr(value), 'came from', index)


Decimal('1') came from [0, 0]
Decimal('2') came from [0, 1]
Decimal('3') came from [0, 2]
Decimal('4') came from [0, 3]
Decimal('5') came from [1, 0]
Decimal('6') came from [1, 1]
Decimal('7') came from [1, 2]
Decimal('8') came from [1, 3]
Decimal('9') came from [2, 0]
Decimal('10') came from [2, 1]
Decimal('11') came from [2, 2]
Decimal('12') came from [2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: I'll definitely have to look into creating these iterable functions. Thanks